# Как сделать синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Синтаксический разбор предложения: Кто хочет много знать,тому надо мало спать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужен синтаксический разбор следующего предложения. Кто хочет много знать, тому надо мало спать. Это простое односоставное предложение или сложно-подчиненное с бессоюзной связью?

Comment: «_…или сложно-подчиненное с бессоюзной связью?_» === А разве такие бывают?

Comment: МИНУСОВКА не требуется. Вопрос отражает стремление автора разобраться в теме., и ему нужно помочь в этом.  Я ставлю ПЛЮС за  этот вопрос. Вопрос сложный, проблем там хватает. Также не надо закрывать вопрос, если на него трудно ответить, это не повод.

Comment: Сложноподчиненных предложений (СПП) с бессоюзной связью действительно не бывает,  но во многих бессоюзных сложных предложениях (БСП) выражены подчинительные отношения (причина, следствие, условие). Таких отношений нет только в однородных БСП (с перечислением или противопоставлением с союзом А).

Answer (score 1):

***Кто** хочет много знать, **тому** надо мало спать.*

**Разбор сложного предложения**

*Кто хочет много знать* (придаточное), *тому надо мало спать* (главное).

1. Это СПП (сложноподчиненное предложение) с местоименной связью *кто — тому*. Придаточное предложение на первом месте, КТО — союзное слово в роли подлежащего.

Главное предложение на втором месте, ТОМУ — указательное слово в роли дополнения (его содержание раскрывает придаточное предложение).

2. **Инверсия** (перестановка) предложений характерна для пословиц разговорного вида.

Прямой порядок слов: *Тому надо мало спать* (главное), *кто хочет много знать* (придаточное).

3. Это СПП **местоименно-определительное** (опорное слово ТОМУ — местоимение). Такая же схема у предложений вида *тот — кто, таков — каков*.

**Разбор простых предложений в составе СПП**

**Главное** (безличное предложение): *надо спать* — составное глагольное сказуемое, *тому* — дополнение.

**Придаточное**: *Кто* — подлежащее, *хочет знать* — составное глагольное сказуемое.

**P.S.** Мне показался интересным вопрос о сближении **простого и сложного** предложений в разговорной речи. **Синтаксическая синонимия** позволяет нам записать ту же мысль в форме простого предложения,  где придаточная часть является дополнением: *Желающему много знать (= любопытному) надо мало спать.*

Такое сближение обеспечивает **инверсия** придаточного дополнительного предложения относительно главного предложения, что характерно для разговорного стиля **пословиц.**

А вот БСП **(бессоюзная связь**) с тем же значением: *Желаешь знать — надо мало спать.*

Comment: @Александр Стрелец   Спасибо за правку.